# Does spring boot offer a standard login and registration support

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I found some tutorials on `Spring Security` Login and registration:

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login-error-handling-localization

http://www.baeldung.com/registration-with-spring-mvc-and-spring-security

However, I am using `Spring Boot` now and would like to find a tutorial for that one as well. Problem is, all I could find was `OAuth2` and `SSO`

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/ (point 28.)

Any idea how to proceed if I want to implement a simple login and registration form with `Spring Boot`?

EDIT:
I found [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) in official documentation. That would do the Login feature, but what about registration?

Answer (score 5):

You would need a UserDetailsService for storing and receiving userdetails, and of course at least 1 service to actually store the user.

For example this service:

```
@Service
public class RegistrationService {

    @Resource
    private MailService mailer;
    @Resource
    private UserDataService userDataService;

    public boolean createRegistration(RegistryCredentials credentials,
            MessageContext context) {
        String username = credentials.getUsername();
        UserData current = new UserData();
        if (userDataService.isAvailable(username)) {
            userDataService.addUserData(username, current);
            return true;
        } else {
            context.addMessage(new MessageBuilder().error().source("username")
                    .code("username.exists").build());
            return false;
        }

    }

    public void saveUserData(RegistryCredentials credentials) {
        UserData current = userDataService.getUserData(credentials
                .getUsername());
        current.setCity(credentials.getCity());
        current.setEmail(credentials.getEmail());
        current.setPassword(credentials.getPassword());
        current.setStreet(credentials.getStreet());
        current.setFirstname(credentials.getFirstname());
        current.setLastname(credentials.getLastname());
        current.setUsername(credentials.getUsername());
        current.setRegistered(new Date());
        Long activationKey = userDataService.updateUserData(current);
        mailer.sendSubscriptionEmail(current, activationKey);
    }

}
```

RegistryCredentials are a standard bean containing the user data fields and validation annotations.
You create the registryCredentials on the registrationpage, check them in to the service, which in turn will create (and persist) the user details.
Of course you will have to register your own service implementation with SpringSecurity, so you'll need this in your Security Configuration:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth,
        UserDataService userDataService) throws Exception {

    auth.userDetailsService(userDataService);
}
```

For a simple, in-memory solution, you could use a UserDataService like this:

```
@Service
public class UserDataService implements UserDetailsService {

    private HashMap<String, UserData> userData = new HashMap<>();
    private HashMap<Long, UserData> activation = new HashMap<>();

    public UserDataService() {
        UserData admin = new UserData();
        admin.setUsername("admin");
        admin.setPassword("password");
        admin.setActive(true);
        userData.put("admin", admin);
    }

    public boolean isAvailable(String username) {
        return !userData.containsKey(username);
    }

    public void addUserData(String username, UserData data) {
        userData.put(username, data);
    }

    public UserData getUserData(String username) {
        return userData.get(username);
    }

    public Long updateUserData(UserData changed) {
        userData.put(changed.getUsername(), changed);
        Long random = new SecureRandom().nextLong();
        activation.put(random, changed);
        return random;
    }

    public UserData activateAccount(Long key) {
        return activation.remove(key);

    }

    public boolean mayActivate(Date d, UserData data) {
        long day = 86400000L;
        Date reg = data.getRegistered();
        reg.setTime(reg.getTime() + day);
        if (d.before(reg)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserData user = getUserData(username);
        if (user != null) {
            return user;
        }
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
    }

}
```

Important is in this case, that `UserData` has to implement `UserDetails` and `Principal` for the Security Authentication to actually be able to work with this.

This particular Solution creates a registration token to use before first login is possible, this is, however, entirely optional, since you can configure the login procedure as you wish.

Comment: Really great answer, thank you. Will try that soon. Although it is strange there is no complete tutorial out there to do such basic thing.

Comment: I think it is going to work. Do you have any idea where may I learn all that? It seems to me that Spring is like a whole new language. Although I know it isn't but all these annotations and a need to know which library and service to use...

Comment: Most of it you can find in the spring docs. Although you have to cross-check different topics to get everything what you want.

However, we had a workshop in which we learned it. Our teacher has shown us everything in the spring docs, though, so.. we didn't have to look for ourselves and could simply work off the provided ones.

And I agree, spring is effectively almost a new language, but is it very easy to use once you understand the basics of the modules =)